# Logout lightdm session does not close session

Tags: centos, rhel, mate, gdm

I have lightdm running on RHEL7.9. But when I try to logout user from vnc session. It doesn't close the vnc session instead it stays with blank screen and the process is not getting exited.

I have also tried "exit_on_failure=true" under Seats configuration. But it will close all the vnc sessions
Any suggestions?

TIA